# Python IDLE - How to type code after a loop

Tags: python, loops, indentation, python-idle

I'm trying to familiarize myself with IDLE by executing the following code from Automate the Boring Stuff with Python by Al Sweigart:

```
name = ""
while name != "Mark":
    print("What is your name?")
    name = input();
print("Thank you")
```

[Syntax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU4gW.png)

For some reason though, I get a syntax error when trying to type the last print statement. I dont know how to get around the indentation / how to be able to type again OUTSIDE of the loop. I understand that only one block of code is executed at a time but I can't seem to be able to incorporate the final print statement. Does anybody know how I can get around this? Thank you very much

Comment: You are most likely running it on IDLE REPL. The REPL basically runs each line/block of code and immediately returns the output of that line/block of code, so what you are trying to achieve here will not actually work on IDLE REPL. What you could do is create a python file (Press Ctrl+N), paste your code there and run it.

Comment: That was what I was thinking too but wanted to make sure I exhausted all my options in IDLE first. Thanks

Comment: What John is telling you *is* an option in IDLE.  Note that you won't see the word "REPL" anywhere in IDLE, it's referred to as the "shell window" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IDLE, put an empty, unindented line after entering this line:

```py
    name = input();
```

Press enter again to make the extra blank line to exit that indented block and your loop should execute after that.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately pressing enter again executes the code and I can't seem to find a workaround

Comment: Interactive Python, whether run directly from a command line or simulated in a GUI Shell such as IDLE, executes a statement at a time.  When you enter a `while` statement, it *should* immediately execute.  If you want to enter a entire program and then execute, enter it in a file, such as with the IDLE editor.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your solution might be very simple.

```
name = input();
```

You don't need the ending semi-colon in Python, remove it so the line is just:

```
name = input()
```

Comment: While the semicolon is unnecessary, it is still permitted, and technically harmless.

Comment: forgot to remove that one. A habit from coming over from java